# Gematria seforim and look up

Tags: gematria-numerology

Are there any seforim, or sites, that explain a specific gematria-value and you can look up with what it is associated with? How would one find the meaning behind it?

I found [this website](https://www.gematrix.org/?word=721), but it not seems legit in my eyes though.

Comment: Gimatria.co.il does that quite nicely

Comment: @יהושעק Thanks. טראמפ (Trump) (just an example) is, according to the method of Baal HaTurim 721. However, according to Gimatria, טראמפ equals 330. Also, it does not really associate it with a Torah-concept?!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot determine the meaning behind a word by looking up words with the same gematria. Equivalent gematrias are a memorable way to *convey* meaning, but not to discover it. For any given value, it's possible to come up with a very long list of Hebrew words or phrases whose gematrias equal that value, doubtless many of them with contradictory implications.

Comment: Interesting. But where to draw the line? How to determine whether your gematria is suitable?

Comment: If it makes a point that you already know is consistent with Torah, and if it will help your audience remember that point, then it's suitable. If not both of those things, then it's narishkeit.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

The following sites can search for gematria occurrences and associations (*you would have to provide your own meaning though*)

[**TorahCalc**](https://www.torahcalc.com) - has some very nice gematria calculation features

My own [**Base Hasefer**](https://basehasefer.com) can (*by selecting גמטריא or אתבש from the search setting panel on the right and then entering numbers or actual Hebrew words into the search bar*):

- search one to many numbers at a time for pesukim containing
  words that match on each gematria entered
- its Frequency Viewer and Object Clouds screens can display
  occurrence-frequency of gematrias that can be filtered by individual
  seforim in Tanach

For all these one can also limit/filter results to individual sections of Tanach.

There are a number of additional ways of using gematria on the site - one example is that in its Lexicon screen, one has a way to generate a list of words that match on gematria value.

Comment: Nice site, well done! How do I search posukim/words/meanings for a specific numerical value?

Comment: @Shmuel - I have edited the wording above to clarify at least how to search specific words.  On can even search for entire pesukim whose gematria totals to a value or range of values with the following visual example https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MtDmxaGFLeAX05yNx7f7MM10YBUgI5bz/view?usp=sharing - for additional specific site questions I suggest contacting info@taryaganalytics.com

Answer (score 0):

I'll actually preface this with what Isaac said in his answer: gematria doesn't teach you what a word, or name, means. At best, it's a cool gimmick that's good for Purim torah and bar mitzva b'rachas, unless sourced. That being said:

---

[גמטריקון](https://www.sefer.org.il/items/3728054-%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%91-%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D) is pretty good, it has a bunch of gematrias for numbers up to 1000, it has more than 40000 individual gematrias. (There are other gematria books available on that site, but I can't testify to their usefulness).

For example, for 330 (טראמפ) it brings ~50 examples, among which are:

> המורה בחסד; חכם הרזים; כבודו במקומו מונח; כי צדיק יהגה חכמה; גילו ברעדה; על רוב טובה

Also this site:

https://www.gimatria.co.il/

Comment: Thanks, but is Gimatria.co.il really reliable? The letter "peh" is 60 according to this site, but the Baal HaTurim says it's 80, also does the sefer "גימטריקון" also explains the Torah-relation with a word?

Comment: @Shmuel where does it say that פ is 60? I also don't understand what you mean by the "Torah relation" with a word?

Comment: My apologies. What I meant was. Let's take Trump, that is 9+200+1+40+80 (330). My question then is, where to look what the Torah tells us about this, and 330 specifically. Does it have a message for us?

Comment: @Shmuel it brings quotes from the Torah, as well as other things

Comment: I don't see that here: https://www.gimatria.co.il/?word=330 @Lo Ani. What is the most common way to search for Gematria connections?

Comment: I just saw your edit. Yeah, that is kinda what I was looking for, explanations on certain values, from a reliable sources. There are many Gematria sites, but I have a certain feeling they are a bitt off.

Comment: Also, why is the letter peh at the end of  "trump" not 800, but 80? The end numbers are 500-900, right?

Comment: @Shmuel not as far as I know, but also the way I searched it was with a regular פ, because that's how you spelled it in the question

Comment: If you want to know what the Torah says about that מנובל, read Yechezkel 29:3-5.